# How to know the adjacent points from another points

Tags: c#, graphics

I am newbie in graphics. I have a panel which I have used to plot some points. Now I will click anywhere in the panel and I need to find the point which is nearest to the Clicked point. Which is the best way to find that. Could someone help me.

@Yahia Actually i have created a some points which will look like

```
. . . .                                                               
. . . .                                                               
. . . .
```

And now i will click in between those points and i need to find the nearest point from where i clicked and color it different.

The code i used is

```
PlotterMap = new Bitmap(this.pnlPlotterMap.Width, this.pnlPlotterMap.Height,     
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);                                                  
BufferGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(PlotterMap);     
BufferGraphics.FillEllipse(brush, plcolplot.XPixel1, plcolplot.YPixel1,2,2);
```

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried ? what is exactly the definition of "nearest" in this case ?

Comment: @Yahia Actually i have created a some points which will look like this

Comment: look for nearest neighbour algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In click event of your panel, pick the point where click has been done. Start creating circles in increasing radius starting with 1 (don't draw this, just create object n code behind) and try to find out which per-defined point intersect with your circle first.

Comment: this seems like a slow method, lookping through the points and calculating the distince using Pyhagorean theorem is way faster i think. Nevertheless your method will work.

Comment: @maheep i was little scared..but now i am trying that..hope that works..shall i simply match the points with my predefined points or is there any equation for that..thanks for the help..

Comment: if you really want to do that (its really slow and not at all mathematical) you have to make sure that you use filled circles and not drawed circles (or you can jump over points if your increment is too big). but honestly:  DONT DO THAT

Comment: @Maheep I didnt drawn any circles but rather looped through my predefined points and used the Pythagorean theorem . also i will look the other methods mentioned.

Comment: using the pythagoraen theorem is perfect. (its whats being done in my answer too in the "(mousePos - p)" part.

Answer (score 3):

the mathematical way to do it would be to calculate the distances.

it will still be way faster than doing the brute-force method of the circles

you could do it with vectors (which exists in .net from 3.5 on) in combination with LINQ:

```
Point mousePos = new Point();
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

var closest = (from Point p in points 
              select new { 
                Vector = (mousePos - p), 
                Point = p }
              ).OrderBy(a => a.Vector.Length).FirstOrDefault();

if (closest != null)
{
    double distance = closest.Vector.Length;
    Point closesPoint = closest.Point;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better than what I had suggested using circles.

Comment: I havent tried LINQ before but might be the first attempt.thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate distances between clicked point and other points, then find shortest distance. How to calculate distance? - use Pythagorean theorem. [Here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) is how to calculate distance between 2 points